# Symfony default controller white page

Tags: php, symfony

After installing a fresh version of symfony via composer

`php composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myProject`

The default welcome page looks like this[image]

All permissions are correct so not sure where the default view is? Anyone seen this before?

Comment: What are you expecting? This is the default view.

Comment: Oh. I was expecting http://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/welcome.png

Comment: AcmeDemoBundle was removed in symfony 2.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what should be displayed.  When you install the standard framework edition, it comes with a default `AppBundle` that has a controller which loads the default index page.  The content of that template simply displays `Homepage`.

Here's the `AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController` call, it renders the `default/index.html.twig` template:

```
return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
```

And here's the `content` section of that template:

```
{% block body %}
Homepage.
{% endblock %}
```

The fact that the Symfony profiler is showing at the bottom is the main indicator that you actually installed Symfony properly.

Here are the files in Symfony 2.7:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig

The screenshot you are looking for existed for the `Acme/DemoBundle` which was the default through Symfony 2.4, but this was removed in Symfony 2.5 in favor of a much more bare-bones `AppBundle`.